# Return value of placement new

Tags: c++, c++14, language-lawyer

Consider the following C++14 code:

```
#include <cassert>
#include <new>
#include <type_traits>

struct NonStandardLayout
{
    // ...
};

int main()
{
    using T = NonStandardLayout;

    std::aligned_storage_t< sizeof(T), alignof(T) > storage;
    T *const valid_ptr = new(static_cast<void *>(&storage)) T;

    T *const maybe_ptr = reinterpret_cast<T *>(&storage);
    assert(maybe_ptr == valid_ptr); // ???

    valid_ptr->T::~T();
    return 0;
}
```

Is it guaranteed by the standard that the assert in the example will never fail, for any type T?

### Discussion

Looking in the latest standard (http://eel.is/c++draft/), I cannot see any reference to this particular scenario but I have found the following paragraphs that arguably points to the answer 'yes'.

Is it correct of me to think that
[expr.new/15]
and
[new.delete.placement/2]
together states that the value of `valid_ptr` will equal the address of `storage`, always?

If so, is it true that the `reinterpret_cast` will yield a pointer to a fully constructed object? Because,
[expr.reinterpret.cast/7],
[expr.static.cast/13]
and
[basic.compound/4]
together seem to indicate that it should be the case.

From my observations, library implementations of the default allocator seem to cast similar to this and without worry! Is it *really* safe to cast like this?

How can we be sure that the two pointers will be the same, or can we?

Comment: damn good first question! you lurked long enough to know [ask]

Comment: Maybe irrelevant, but I read somewhere that the `malloc` of a system is guaranteed to return memory aligned for any data type.

Comment: It's not formally guaranteed, but by *reasoning* about distinct pointer values you can deduce that it will never fail on a PC. As far as the standard is concerned the `reinterpret_cast` result can be any pointer value here, except nullpointer, because it's not used. The only guaranteed usage (apart from comparing to nullpointer) is to cast it back.

Comment: The answer is the definition of `std::aligned_storage_t`. If it garanteers this property, then yes. This has nothing to do with how placement new works.

Comment: This example is basically [half the motivation behind `std::launder`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4303.html) (the other half being Core 1776).

Comment: @T.C: The other half of the motivation seems to be to add obscurity and complexity in order to support an interpretation of the standard that itself is in support of a particular implementation. Ouch. Code using this will read like utter nonsense to most every developer.

Comment: I'm inclined to say that they "represent the same address", so that they compare equal. However, `maybe_ptr` does not actually *point to* the `T` object (since the `T` object and the `aligned_storage_t` object are not pointer-interconvertible), so you cannot use it to access the `T` object without `launder`ing it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm surprised no one has mentioned this cheap counterexample yet:

```
struct foo {
  static foo f;
  // might seem dubious but doesn't violate anything
  void* operator new(size_t, void* p) {return &f;}
};
```

[Demo on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2c030d00c5f05a6b).

Unless a class-specific placement version is called, however, your assertion should hold. Both expressions have to represent the same address as explained in the other answer (the main point being that the standard non-allocating `operator new` simply returns the pointer argument and the new expression not doing anything fancy), and neither of these is a pointer past the end of some object so, by [expr.eq]/2, they compare equal.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin Are you sure that this applies to class specific overrides, i.e. static members as in the above example? It seems that this paragraph addresses the global versions?

Comment: Thinking more about it, the standard explicitly allows class-specific placement new operators. So I take that comment back.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin First off, your paragraph number is incorrect (18.6.2.3), and secondly, please use the textual form instead, like [new.delete.placement]. Numbers do change every now and then, and the most up-to-date draft is subject to a big clause numbering change induced by ISO (clause 18 is now 21). You can see that already on eel.is/c++draft.

Comment: Sam's answer from last year discounts this as a possibility, doesn't it? You are not returning the pointer you were given. Seems like you're assuming `&f` == `p` but there's no guarantee of that, particularly as the type has been stated to be non-standard-layout.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition I don't get it; I answered the question. My code is valid and would break his assertion. The specification Sam quoted does not apply to user-defined operator news (and if you think it does, please do provide a citation).

Comment: I didn't look at it very closely or check the standard. If you reckon that the restriction is only upon the library's "default" impl and no such constraint is placed upon user-defined ones, then I guess that's fine

Comment: I guess it does not matter then what the type is, as long as it does not have a funny operator new :D
I will accept this because of a technicallity (is that not why we are all here?). However, there is still the question of where the standard states that "the new expression [does] not [do] anything fancy", because we all know that aint true; see the comments of Sam's post. Maybe someone will ask a new question about that? *hint hint*

Comment: @godpusti The comments on Sam's post refer to the new[] expression, i.e. the array form. The non-array form does not do anything fancy, because there's nothing fancy to be done.

Answer (score 3):

> 18.6.1.3 Placement forms [new.delete.placement]
>
> void* operator new(std::size_t size, void* ptr) noexcept;
>
> Returns: ptr.

It is unambiguously specified that the placement `new` operator returns whatever pointer is passed to it. "Returns: ptr". Can't get any clearer than that.

That, pretty much, seals the deal for me as far as "the return value from placement new" goes: placement `new` does nothing to the pointer it places, and it always returns the same pointer.

Everything else in your question relates to any other changes that might occur as the result of the other casts; but you're asking specifically about the return value from placement `new`, so I take it that you're accepting that all other conversion are type-conversions only, and have no effect on the actual pointer, and you were only asking about placement new -- but it would also be possible to go through the other casts, and make a similar determination.

Comment: The things is that the array form of operator new also returns `ptr` [new.delete.placement/5], but we all know that `new(ptr) int[10]` does not return `ptr` due to [expr.new/15.4]. So what does the non array version do?

Comment: There's a difference between the placement allocation function and the *new-expression*.

Comment: *new-expression* calls the placement allocation function. See 5.3.4 (13), and (14).  "The new-placement syntax is used to supply additional arguments to an allocation function... [Example:
— new T results in a call of operator new(sizeof(T)),
— new(2,f) T results in a call of operator new(sizeof(T),2,f)]" Therefore: `new(ptr) T` calls `operator new(sizeof(T), ptr)`. Q.E.D.

Comment: SamVarshavchik: Consider @godpusti's comment about the array form, together with the fact that for items that need to be destroyed, the array length needs to be stored somewhere so each item can be destroyed. Also, consider that T.C. is almost always right.

Comment: The question did not reference the array form. For the use case given in the question, this looks cut and dry to me. As far as all the white noise goes: I do remember a long time ago when I also often believed that I was always right. I'm happy to report that this was a long time ago, and since then I simply grew up. I'm open to reading a convincing argument, or an alternative answer that either reaches a different conclusion based on other evidence, or identifies a flaw in my cite; if so I'll delete it. But, as of now, I believe that my answer is correct.

Comment: Technically the function could modify `ptr` before returning it. But I agree that this isn't what the standard means :D